# Can we develop a spring application on tomcat server and deploy it on some other application server?

Tags: spring, tomcat, application-server

Can we develop a struts+spring+hibernate application on tomcat server and later deploy it on say Web Sphere or Web logic Application servers?

If this can be done please explain the process of deployment? If this cannot be done please let me know the reason?

I am new to working with application servers. An explanation will be greatly helpful.

Thank you,
user181333

Comment: Please, specify your application a bit. Most of the time Spring is server-agnostic but if you used something like a [TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/instrument/classloading/tomcat/TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader.html) then you may have some troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, Spring is application server agnostic (but well, people [always](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/10/19/spring-3-on-a-java-ee-6-server/), [always](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=61023) debate such things).  That means that you should have no trouble deploying web applications in different containers.

Anyways, some portability issues may arise. The only ones I am aware of is [classpath loading resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#resources-classpath-wildcards) because of the servlet container implementation of class loading. Another is if you registered a [TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/instrument/classloading/tomcat/TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader.html) or something similar. And maybe [JtaTransactionManager lookups](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#transaction-application-server-integration).

For exact details in concern of deploying a web app just refer to the documentation of your specific application server.